# How long does it take each thread timeslice in Windows XP?

Tags: multithreading, windows-xp, operating-system

I am trying to find out how long does it take each thread timeslice (quantum) in Windows but the only information that I found out is about the clock ticks being from 15 to 20ms or 20-30ms.
How can I find this information ? 
I think it may vary from OS to OS, but I am not certain.
I appreciate any suggestion on this subject.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe there is (or used to be) a system setting somewhere that affects this too. Something with "optimize for desktop" (smaller timeslice) or "optimize for server" (larger timeslice). Either way, it is definitely system-dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259025) has some information on Windows 2000 Server editions:

> Currently in Windows, 3 quantums are equal to either 10 milliseconds (single processor) or 15 milliseconds (multiple-processor Pentium). This depends on the hardware abstraction layer (HAL) selected for your computer. Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) HALs may have a different value. Time slices that are fixed at 36 quantums are currently used when background services are selected (as you might choose in a typical server installation).

So on a multi-processor Pentium, a quantum would be 5 ms and a time slice as long as 180 ms. That seems quite large to me, though...

Comment: That is in the range of what I remember from my Operating Systems course around that time. AFAIK shorter time slices were (or still are being) used on workstations and terminal servers. Time slice length is essentially a trade-off between performance and responsiveness: shorter time slices mean more context switches per time unit, which degrades performance. Longer time slices mean the reaction from the app you’re trying to interact with may appear sluggish, hence the shorter time slices for systems running end-user apps.

Answer (score 1):

Time slices not only vary between operating systems, but between processors as well. i can't think of a way to find out for certain (as micro-benchmarking will not work due to the OS being in the way regarding time slice allocations).