# overhead of thread-synchronization via Events

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, events, thread-synchronization

I am experimenting with multithreaded synchronization at the moment. For a backround I have a set of about 100000 objects - possibly more - I want to process in different ways multiple times per second.

Now the thing concerning me most is the performance of the synchronization.

This is what I think should work just fine (I omitted all security aspects as this is just a testprogram and in case of an error the program will just crash ..). I wrote two funktions, the first to be executed by the main thread of the program, the second to be run by all additional threads.

```
void SharedWorker::Start()
{
    while (bRunning)
    {
        // Send the command to start task1
        SetEvent(hTask1Event);

        // Do task1 (on a subset of all objects) here

        // Wait for all workers to finish task1
        WaitForMultipleObjects(<NumberOfWorkers>, <ListOfTask1WorkerEvents>, TRUE, INFINITE);

        // Reset the command for task1
        ResetEvent(hTask1Event);

        // Send the command to start task2
        SetEvent(hTask2Event);

        // Do task2 (on a subset of all objects) here

        // Wait for all workers to finish task2
        WaitForMultipleObjects(<NumberOfWorkers>, <ListOfTask2WorkerEvents>, TRUE, INFINITE);

        // Reset the command for task2
        ResetEvent(hTask2Event);

        // Send the command to do cleanup
        SetEvent(hCleanupEvent);

        // Do some (on a subset of all objects) cleanup

        // Wait for all workers to finish cleanup
        WaitForMultipleObjects(<NumberOfWorkers>, <ListOfCleanupWorkerEvents>, TRUE, INFINITE);

        // Reset the command for cleanup
        ResetEvent(hCleanupEvent);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI WorkerThreads(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    while (bRunning)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hTask1Event, INFINITE);

        // Unset finished cleanup
        ResetEvent(hCleanedUp);

        // Do task1 (on a subset of all objects) here

        // Signal finished task1
        SetEvent(hTask1);

        WaitForSingleObject(hTask2Event, INFINITE);

        // Reset task1 event
        ResetEvent(hTask1);

        // Do task2 (on a subset of all objects) here

        // Signal finished task2
        SetEvent(hTask2);

        WaitForSingleObject(hCleanupEvent, INFINITE);

        // Reset update event
        ResetEvent(hTask2);

        // Do cleanup (on a subset of all objects) here

        // Signal finished cleanup
        SetEvent(hCleanedUp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To point out my requirements, I'll just give you a little example:
Say we got the 100000 objects from above, split into 8 subsets of 12500 objects each, a modern multicore processor with 8 logical cores. The relevant part is the time. All tasks must be performed in about 8ms.

My questions are now, can I get a significant boost in time from split processing or is the synchronization via events too expensive? or is there maybe even another way of synchronizing threads with less effort or process time if all the tasks need to be done this way?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without knowing more about your tasks, and their resource requirements (CPU, I/O). In general you should try to minimize the time spent by your thread(s) in wait state. Async processing is one alternative to inter-thread signalling, but that may not be possible in your task execution.

Comment: Oh yea sorry, totally forgot about my resource requirements. Task 1 and 2 are pure CPU, clean up is only for delayed deletion of objects from task 2. Async processing is unfortunately no alternative as task1, task2 and cleanup is a fixed sequence which must maintain order and ever task must be finished befor the next one may start.

Comment: It sounds like you might be able to use something like OpenMP rather than rolling your own threading/signalling.  That's well-suited to running similar, sequenced tasks in parallel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your tipp wiht OpenMP, allready stuck my nose into it. Do you have some experiences with OpenMP? I get some unexpected results from my first performance tests. Made a test with a loop measuring the time taken for a fixed number of iterations (no work so far as I want to know which one consumes less time). So I took one million iterations as a goal. In Debug Mode OpenMP ran at 16.4k iterations per second(ips) at 100% CPU, in Release Mode it ran at 440k ips at 100% CPU. My solution ran at 46k ips at 33% CPU in both modes. From my point of view OpenMP's results are strage?

Comment: No experience, just sounded like your pattern would fit better into that than resorting to custom task scheduling

Answer (score 0):

If your processing of a single object is fast, do not split it between threads. The thread synchronization on windows will eat well over 50 ms on every context switch. This time is not used by system, but just the time when something else is running on a system.

However, if every object processing will take around 8ms, there is a point of scheduling the work across pool of threads. However, object processing may vary a bit, and in large counts worker threads would complete the work in a different moment.

Better approach is to organize a synchronized object queue, to which you add objects to process, and from which you take them from processing. Furthermore, as processing of a single object considerably lower, than scheduling interval of a thread, it is good to take them into processing thread in batches (like 10-20). You can estimate the best number of worker threads in your pool and the best size of a batch with tests.

So the pseudocode can look like:

```
main_thread:
    init queue
    start workers

    set counter to 100000
    add 100000 objects to queue
    while (counter) wait();

worker_thread:
    while (!done)
        get up to 10 objects from queue
        process objects
        counter -= processed count
        if (counter == 0) notify done
```

Comment: Please provide a justification for your statement that context switching takes 50ms on Windows.

Comment: Thread pools have a different purpose from what I need. My loop continually runs and perfomes the same three tasks over and over again until it gets stopped. The set remains mainly the same (less than ten new/deleted objects per iteration) so a synchronized queue would be a big overhead. Moreover one iteration of the loop may take 8ms, not the processing of a single object.

Comment: @SteveTownsend I don't have an accurate figure, however here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898344/how-long-does-it-take-each-thread-timeslice-in-windows-xp. In my experience threads may loose considerably more then 50 ms on context switch (as in question comments).

Comment: @user2186380 If a whole processing takes 8 ms, you don't want to play with multiple threads.

Comment: That discussion is about time slicing - neither q nor comments say anything about context switching

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk - you are wrong, CPU-bound tasks are ideal for multithreading.

Comment: @SteveTownsend They are indeed, but not when processing the whole data batch takes only 8ms. Windows by no way a real-time OS, so there are no guarantees on system reaction over scheduler events. Adding threads just to split processing would actually cause extra delay on synchronizing them at some point. I'm not talking about CPU time spent, I'm talking about clock time. Even if you have ten tasks that takes 10 ms each, it might be faster to run them in non-paralleled loop, as a single wait may take longer then 100ms. Ok, I mainly deal with server systems, that always have something to do...

Comment: 'over 50 ms on every context switch' - I don't think so!

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk 10ms is quite a long time in terms of thread signaling/scheduling.  10ms tasks are well worth running on multiple cores.  I would only worry much if the tasks took only 100ns.

Comment: @MartinJames I've understood all processing (100000 objects) takes 8ms (see comment #2). So individual object processing is 80ns. Isn't it what you've said?

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk - 'split into 8 subsets of 12500 objects each'

Comment: @MartinJames 12500 objects give processing time of 1 millisecond. I would still insist that on windows, re-synchronizing threads would take considerably more time, then that. You must be extremely lucky to get execution continue within 7 milliseconds after being blocked on event handle (or critical section, semaphore, etc). 1. each worker thread needs to wake up quickly. 2. Control thread needs to wake up quickly after workers are done. Having all that done in less, then 8 milliseconds (to get any time improvement) is unrealistic expectation in my opinion. Just compute probability of such evt

Comment: I must be continually very lucky.

Comment: 'Benchmarking will show that it takes less than 2 microseconds from the time the event is set to the time the wait function awakes.' - quote from someone who actually tried it.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure about your environment. Here are my results: CPU-intensive task, run a) by 8 threads (1/8th of task each), b) by single thread on 4-core CPU/Win7. Single threaded: 7.5 milliseconds (avg). Multithreaded: 3.5 milliseconds (avg). It is better then I have expected, though the PC has not been running any other background processes, but it is not even close to 2 microseconds context switch. The test has been simplified in comparison to original question: only 1-stage processing has been done.