# Numerous short lived tasks slower when multithreaded even with threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, threadpool

### Background

I currently have a linear physics engine (but this question does not require physics engine knowledge), parts of which I'm experimenting with multithreading with the hope of increasing efficiency.

One such section is the broad phase, in this case this involves moving through all the objects along all 3 axes to check which overlap (any which occur on all axes are considered to have collided in broad phase). The 3 axis sweeps are, apart from using common objects, completely independent and so seemed a good place for multithreading.

In order to avoid the possibility of blocking between threads each of these 3 processes takes a local copy of all data it wants to use before (if applicable) going multithreaded

While these sweeps are a significant bottle neck they are very short lived, a sweep typically lasts 1-4ms. This is a real time application where the code is run 60 times a second so total tick time is at maximum 17ms so 1-4ms is a long time for me. Because these sweeps are short lived I have used a thread pool. Specifically a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)`, 3 for the 3 axes.

My test computer was a dual core with hyper threading, so up to 4 threads should be comfortable.  <sub>Checked using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();`</sub>

### Question

When running the following test code, in which numerous short lived tasks were run either single threaded or multithreaded using a threadpool the multithreaded version was much slower; see profile data. This was the case even when the multithreaded parts had no objects in common. Why was this and is there any way to run many short lived (1-4ms) tasks concurrently?

Even making the tasks much much larger only makes the multithreaded version approach the single threaded in performance not exceed it as I had expected, which makes me think i'm doing something seriously wrong.

[image]

### Test code

```
public class BroadPhaseAxisSweep implements Callable<Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor>>  {

    static final int XAXIS=0;
    static final int YAXIS=1;
    static final int ZAXIS=2;

    int axis; 
    int[] axisIndicies;
    boolean[] isStatic;
    boolean[] isLightWeight; 
    boolean[] isCollidable; 

    //orders the same as axisIndicies
    double[] starts;
    double[] ends;

    private static ExecutorService sweepPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public BroadPhaseAxisSweep(int axis, List<TestObject> allObjects) {
        //all data that will be used by the thread is cached internally to avoid 
        //any concurrent access issues

        this.axis = axis;

        //allObjects is in reality unsorted, axisIndicies holds sorted indices
        //in this case allObjects just "happens" to be already sorted
        this.axisIndicies =new int[allObjects.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<allObjects.size();i++){
            axisIndicies[i]=i;
        }
        isStatic=new boolean[allObjects.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<allObjects.size();i++){
            isStatic[i]=allObjects.get(i).isStatic();
        }
        isLightWeight=new boolean[allObjects.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<allObjects.size();i++){
            isLightWeight[i]=allObjects.get(i).isLightWeightPhysicsObject();
        }
        isCollidable=new boolean[allObjects.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<allObjects.size();i++){
            isCollidable[i]=allObjects.get(i).isCollidable();
        }

        starts=new double[allObjects.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<allObjects.size();i++){
            starts[i]=allObjects.get(i).getStartPoint();
        }
        ends=new double[allObjects.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<allObjects.size();i++){
            ends[i]=allObjects.get(i).getEndPoint();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> call() throws Exception {
        return axisSweep_simple(axisIndicies);
    }

    private Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> axisSweep_simple(int[] axisIndicies){

        Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> thisSweep =new HashSet();


        for(int i=0;i<starts.length;i++){
            if (isCollidable[axisIndicies[i]]){
                double activeObjectEnd=ends[i];
                //sweep forwards until an objects start is before out end
                for(int j=i+1;j<starts.length;j++){
                    //j<startXsIndicies.length is the bare mininmum contrain, most js wont get that far
                    if ((isStatic[axisIndicies[i]]&& isStatic[axisIndicies[j]]) || ((isLightWeight[axisIndicies[i]]&& isLightWeight[axisIndicies[j]]))){
                        //if both objects are static or both are light weight then they cannot by definition collide, we can skip
                        continue;
                    }


                    if (activeObjectEnd>starts[j]){
                        PotentialCollisionPrecursor potentialCollision=new PotentialCollisionPrecursor(getObjectNumberFromAxisNumber(i),getObjectNumberFromAxisNumber(j));
                            thisSweep.add(potentialCollision);
                    }else{
                        break; //this is as far as this active object goes

                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return thisSweep;
    }


    private int getObjectNumberFromAxisNumber(int number){
        return axisIndicies[number];
    }


     public static void main(String[] args){
         int noOfObjectsUnderTest=250;

         List<TestObject> testObjects=new ArrayList<>();

         Random rnd=new Random();
         double runningStartPosition=0;
         for(int i=0;i<noOfObjectsUnderTest;i++){
             runningStartPosition+=rnd.nextDouble()*0.01;
             testObjects.add(new TestObject(runningStartPosition));
         }

         while(true){
             runSingleTreaded(testObjects);
             runMultiThreadedTreaded(testObjects);
         }

     }

    private static void runSingleTreaded(List<TestObject> testObjects) {
        try {
            //XAXIS used over and over again just for test
            Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> xSweep=(new BroadPhaseAxisSweep(XAXIS,testObjects)).call();
            Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> ySweep=(new BroadPhaseAxisSweep(XAXIS,testObjects)).call();
            Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> zSweep=(new BroadPhaseAxisSweep(XAXIS,testObjects)).call();

            System.out.println(xSweep.size()); //just so JIT can't possibly optimise out
            System.out.println(ySweep.size()); //just so JIT can't possibly optimise out
            System.out.println(zSweep.size()); //just so JIT can't possibly optimise out
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //bad practice, example only
            Logger.getLogger(BroadPhaseAxisSweep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void runMultiThreadedTreaded(List<TestObject> testObjects) {
        try {
            //XAXIS used over and over again just for test
            Future<Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor>> futureX=sweepPool.submit(new BroadPhaseAxisSweep(XAXIS,testObjects));
            Future<Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor>> futureY=sweepPool.submit(new BroadPhaseAxisSweep(XAXIS,testObjects));
            Future<Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor>> futureZ=sweepPool.submit(new BroadPhaseAxisSweep(XAXIS,testObjects));

            Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> xSweep=futureX.get();
            Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> ySweep=futureY.get();
            Set<PotentialCollisionPrecursor> zSweep=futureZ.get();

            System.out.println(xSweep.size()); //just so JIT can't possibly optimise out
            System.out.println(ySweep.size()); //just so JIT can't possibly optimise out
            System.out.println(zSweep.size()); //just so JIT can't possibly optimise out
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //bad practice, example only
            Logger.getLogger(BroadPhaseAxisSweep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    public static class TestObject{

        final boolean isStatic;
        final boolean isLightWeight;
        final boolean isCollidable;
        final double startPointOnAxis;
        final double endPointOnAxis; 

        public TestObject(double startPointOnAxis) {
            Random rnd=new Random();
            this.isStatic = rnd.nextBoolean();
            this.isLightWeight =  rnd.nextBoolean();
            this.isCollidable =  rnd.nextBoolean();
            this.startPointOnAxis = startPointOnAxis;
            this.endPointOnAxis =startPointOnAxis+0.2*rnd.nextDouble();
        }

        public boolean isStatic() {
            return isStatic;
        }

        public boolean isLightWeightPhysicsObject() {
            return isLightWeight;
        }

        public boolean isCollidable() {
            return isCollidable;
        }

        public double getStartPoint() {
            return startPointOnAxis;
        }

        public double getEndPoint() {
            return endPointOnAxis;
        }
    }

}

public class PotentialCollisionPrecursor {
    //holds the object numbers of a potential collision, can be converted to a real PotentialCollision using a list of those objects
    private final int rigidBodyNumber1;
    private final int rigidBodyNumber2; 


    public PotentialCollisionPrecursor(int rigidBodyNumber1, int rigidBodyNumber2) {
        if (rigidBodyNumber1<rigidBodyNumber2){
            this.rigidBodyNumber1 = rigidBodyNumber1;
            this.rigidBodyNumber2 = rigidBodyNumber2;
        }else{
            this.rigidBodyNumber1 = rigidBodyNumber2;
            this.rigidBodyNumber2 = rigidBodyNumber1;
        }
    }

    public int getRigidBodyNumber1() {
        return rigidBodyNumber1;
    }

    public int getRigidBodyNumber2() {
        return rigidBodyNumber2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 67 * hash + this.rigidBodyNumber1;
        hash = 67 * hash + this.rigidBodyNumber2;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final PotentialCollisionPrecursor other = (PotentialCollisionPrecursor) obj;
        if (this.rigidBodyNumber1 != other.rigidBodyNumber1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.rigidBodyNumber2 != other.rigidBodyNumber2) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

### ThreadPools of differing sizes

After single threaded the next fastest is a pool of 2/3 threads, then the slowest of all is a single thread in a thread pool (unsurprisingly as that has all the overhead and none of the gains)

[image]

### Unnaturally large tasks size

To test if the problem was simply having too small tasks for threading I increased the task size to around 100ms. These gave even more confusing results; any number of thread between 1 and 3 is approximately the same speed and is slower than single threaded

[image]

Comment: Rampant speculation - [CPU stalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#CPU_stalls).

Comment: In order to measure the overhead, I'd try to create a `newFixedThreadPool(1)`. And maybe also `newFixedThreadPool(2)` as hyperthreading is not exactly doubling performance.

Comment: why YAXIS and ZAXIS are never used?

Comment: @Alexei it was part of my removing this part from the larger program. In the real version they are used (I should probably indicate that in the question itself - will do when not on mobile)

Comment: @maaartinus I've added those tests, unsuprisingly a single thread in multithread "mode" is the slowest then 2/3 threads are more or less the same

Comment: This makes sense. On my computer the multi-threaded run is faster by maybe 30%. To me it looks like the copying is more expensive than the computation. Btw., don't feel obliged to accept an answer before your problem gets really solved. This would lower the chance you get a better answer later.

Comment: @maaartinus that is interesting, is your machine a quad core? I included the copy in both the multitheaded and single threaded tests so hopefully (even if it is an expensive operation) it shouldn't skew the results. (In the multitheaded version the copy occures in the single threaded preamble however). The copy may ultimately not even be nessisary,  I just wanted to avoid concurrent access as a variable

Comment: Yes, Core i5-2400. I must be doing something wrong, as I'm getting about 0.2 ms per 1000 iterations. If all the data get only read, then there's nothing to gain by copying. The only thing you need is visibility, which is given by `submit`. By copying you're only increasing the memory footprint. The cores are capable of getting the data from each other's cache pretty fast and the L3 cache is shared (copied data => more misses).

Comment: @maaartinus Thank you for saying that, it sent me down a new line of investigation and basically its my profiler (standard netbeans profiler). I don't know why but it seems to wildly slow down the non main threads disproportionately to the main thread. Doing a manual profile using `System.nanoTime()` I get per (set of 3) operation times of SingleTreaded 0.31ms and 0.23ms with 3 threads (and 1 thread 0.36 and 2 threads 0.26). Its obvious that the profiler slows things down but I hadn't realised it **unevenly** slowed things down.

Comment: @maaartinus I wouldn't have got here without your help so if you feel like writing this comment thread as an answer I’ll happily accept. Alternatively I’ll post a short answer explaining that it was the profiler

Comment: Nice.... yes, I'll write an answer tonight. Actually, I had some problems with the profiler some long time ago. I guess it tries to do too many things, like measuring the memory allocations and this goes in the way. Now your figures are pretty similar to mine, so I guess they make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I promised to summarize all the findings here... it's rather confusing as the main culprit is the profiler which slows down the *non main threads disproportionately* to the main thread. Maybe it uses atomic counters for tracking it's data and maybe their's overhead is so high it leads to such non-sensible results.

Measuring the time manually gives better results, namely a multi-threading speedup of 30-40 %. This makes sense as there's big sequential overhead due to data copying.

This copying is neither necessary nor useful. It's unnecessary as all threads only read shared data. It's useless as reading shared variables is no slower than reading an own copy thereof:

- the cores are capable of getting the data from each other's cache pretty fast
- they place a copy of them into their local L1 and L2 caches (the "shared" state of the [MESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) protocol)
- the L3 cache is shared, which means that needlessly copied data imply more L3 misses due to higher memory footprint

Comment: In the real version of this program, profiled manually, avoiding the copy made the multitheaded version look even better. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 3):

If your broad sweeps are only taking a few milliseconds, you're probably better off doing everything synchronously. The effort required to reserve a thread pool thread (on Windows) takes longer than 5ms. Not to mention that you still have to move data around between threads and wait on context switches and then finally put the threads back where you found them.

This whole process is likely to just degrade performance, especially since you're taking local copies of the data. If each sweep was naturally independent and took upwards of 500ms, you could probably benefit from some concurrency model like you have implemented.

One interesting thing to note is that graphics processors these days come with embedded co-processors dedicated to physics calculations. The reason they're so good at doing things like this is because they have sometimes thousands of processor cores all running at relatively low clock rates. This means that they're very good for taking on lots of small-ish tasks concurrently. You may want to try interfacing with a graphics processor directly to offload the physics processing into that kind of environment rather than work with it on a general CPU.

Comment: I'm using my thread pool many many times if that helps (n fact it is created only once)

Comment: @RichardTingle That is good and is typically how you would do things. It saves time by not needing to allocate new stack space for each thread each time you need a new thread. However, the issue at this point isn't that. It's mostly because you're overly parallelizing a task which is fast on its own. Your data copy to prepare for concurrent processing may even be more expensive than just executing the task on a single thread, depending on the allocated size of your collection.

Comment: Graphics processor may be an intersting idea, I tried a naive approach a while back with that but found that data transfer to the GPU was the main bottleneck. However, I didn't really know what I was doing then (whether I know what I'm doing now is yet to be seen)

Comment: For the purposes of the test I did the data copy even in the single threaded case (even though that is stupid)

Comment: Another thing to note: On Windows there is a [minimum time slice that can be given to a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898344/how-long-does-it-take-each-thread-timeslice-in-windows-xp), which means that a task that takes only 1 ms might then leave the processor idle for 4 ms before another thread can be scheduled.

Comment: @RichardTingle Yep! Exactly. I worked on a physics engine a while back and we had a similar issue. Our solution was to write very specific code and do feature detection to take advantage of the latest and greatest DirectX APIs. We ended up using 3D textures and representing our entire world on the GPU, all the time; we never transferred terrain off of the GPU as it was all procedural anyway and we just needed to apply textures in the rendering engine.

Comment: @RussellZahniser Good point. That's yet another downside to concurrently executing short lived tasks.

Comment: 'The effort required to reserve a thread pool thread (on Windows) takes longer than 5ms' - really?

Comment: 'task that takes only 1 ms might then leave the processor idle for 4 ms before another thread can be scheduled' - really?

Comment: @RussellZahniser & Michael Interesting, multithreading may be simply inappropriate for this then. I shall stick with single threaded in the short term with a view to investigating GPU physics in the long term

Comment: A set of tasks that takes 1-4ms each is well worth threading off onto a pool. The idea that signaling/queuing a task onto a pool thread taking 500ms, or even 5ms, is just ridiculous.  100us would be an overestimate.  You are just spreading thread FUD.   Whatever the OP's problem is, over-short tasks is not the reason.

Comment: If you want youi pool to run effectively, stop copying bulk stuff into and out of queues, like M J Grey says.

Comment: @MartinJames Are you suggesting that the problem isn't so much the size of the task but that the data transfer between threads should be small compared to the size of the task to be performed? So dataIn+dataOut << taskSize. I knew this was the case for GPU based concurrency, I didn't realise it was the same for regular multithreading

Comment: @MartinJames I never claimed that signaling or any kind of queue took over 500ms with respect to accessing a pool thread. I just made a test harness in assembly using FASM and called `SubmitThreadpoolWork`. The call timer indicated that the function returned in 11.226ms on a minimally loaded (<1%) Windows Server 2012 system that has 20 cores. This is the base case for pushing work onto a thread pool. If you have 50 work items that each take 5ms, you would want to compute them in sequence on a single thread or divide and conquer more than 10 of them at a time. Where did you get 100us?

Comment: @RichardTingle Since you have mentioned that you will be using the advice in this answer and comments other users have provided, would you mind accepting it as the answer? :)

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray - my own testing, years ago, on a Pentium III

Comment: I'm leaving the question without an accepted for the mean time in case it is possible (considering comment discussion). If nothing else comes in I'll accept in a bot though

Comment: @MartinJames You were correct (see comments on question and accepted answer) basically my profiler was getting upset (still not sure why) and wildly overreporting the secondary thread times. Without the profiler my tasks were approximately 0.2ms and were still worth multithreading (by a small margin)

Comment: @RichardTingle How long does the batch take to complete with and without parallelization?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray SingleTreaded 0.31ms and 0.23ms with 3 threads (per set of 3 time). Measured over a large number of cycles with System.nanoTime()

Comment: @RichardTingle So you might actually be seeing some optimizations being done by the runtime or better overall time allocation for your application from the processor. Since it's measured over a large number of cycles, you may be getting good cache hits as time goes forward. It may or may not be the threading, is what I am getting at. It would be interesting to see a very low level implementation of your solution and profile that; but I don't expect you to go and play with that hah. Threading is more of an art than a science I think. Sometimes it makes a lot of sense, other times it doesn't.